# How to maintain duplicate record in database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

My table contains two columns Title and Description.
I want to provide a functionality to user to create duplicate page for existing page.

Like for existing page database store value like.

Title1 , Description1

When user clicks on duplicate page button I want to create a duplicate entry for the existing page like this.

1) Click First Time

Copy_1_Title1,
Description1

2) Click Second Time

Copy_2_Title1,
Description1

How can I create this type of functionality ? How should be my database for this ? Is this a proper way ?

Comment: I have a possible answer, but I'd like to know why you'd want to do this first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should create third column and name it for example **copy_number**, and then before creating record you can find it by **title** and if title exist you can get value of **copy_number** and increment it. Then you can use this number to display titles as you wish:
"copy_#{record.copy_number}_#{record.title}" or something like this.

Comment: I'd name the column version, since that's what's really happening here. But other than that, you're quite right. Have an upvote

Answer (score 1):

@bor1s has suggested very right solution.

But for the interest you can use this mthod for duplication :)

```
class Page < AR::Base
  def duplicate
    # new_page = self.clone
    new_page = Page.new self.attributes.except(:id, :created_at, :updated_at)
    copy = (self.title.match(/Copy_(\d)+.*/).try([1]) || 0) + 1
    new_page.title = "Copy_#{copy}_#{self.title}"
    new_page.save
  end
end
```

Comment: @flOOr self.clone will not change the updated_at and created_at also for the new object. Is there any way to create clone without timestamps ?